# StreamTokenizer stops when it hits a slash

Tags: java, tokenize

Consider this program , found on tutorial points (where `br` is a BufferedReader object):

```
boolean eof = false;
// Parse incoming request
StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
do {
    int token = st.nextToken();

    switch (token) {
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
            System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
            eof = true;
            break;

        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
            System.out.println("End of Line encountered.");
            break;

        case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
            System.out.println("Word: " + st.sval);
            break;

        case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
            System.out.println("Number: " + st.nval);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println((char) token + " encountered.");

            if (token == '!') {
                eof = true;
            }
    }
    } while (!eof);
```

This snippet works on strings like `"Hello this is a string"` where it will print out:

`Word: Hello`

`Word: this`

`Word: is`

`Word: a`

`Word: string`

But if I do something like this: `"Hello /this is a string"` It will only print out

`Word: Hello`

Why is this, and how can i solve it?

Comment: Just an idea: " / " is interpreted as beginning of a comment?

Comment: Does it just print "Word: Hello" and then just stop? Or does it crash, exit, or print "End of file encountered". From your code, it looks impossible to just print "Hello" and then nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slash / is not treated as an ordinary character in the StreamTokenizer class. You can change that default behavior by using the ordinaryChar method:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StreamTokenizerSO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String aString = "Hello /this is a string";
        Reader inputString = new StringReader(aString);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputString);

        boolean eof = false;
// Parse incoming request
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);

        st.ordinaryChar('/');

        do {
            int token = st.nextToken();

            switch (token) {
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                    System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
                    eof = true;
                    break;

                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
                    System.out.println("End of Line encountered.");
                    break;

                case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                    System.out.println("Word: " + st.sval);
                    break;

                case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                    System.out.println("Number: " + st.nval);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println((char) token + " encountered.");

                    if (token == '!') {
                        eof = true;
                    }
            }
        } while (!eof);
    }
}
```

Found this by Googling "StreamTokenizer forward slash" and got this old link: http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java061.htm